# javascript banners freezes on first banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, banner

I have two banners which I added recently to my website and I'd like to change the banners every 5 seconds,
unfortunately, it shows only the first one and freezes

this is my whole code for foreach data

```js
var links = ["http://site", "http://site"];
var images = ["/uploads/ad1.png", "/uploads/ad2.png"];
var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function() {
  if (links.length == i) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i];
    document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i];
    i++;

  }
}, 500);
```

```html
   

<?php  foreach ($messages as $message){

    ?>

                 

                    <a href="?id= <?php echo $message['message_id']?>" class="waves-effect waves-light"> details <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left ml-2"></i>

                </div>

                <br>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center">

                <a id="bannerLink" href="http://site" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
                    <img id="bannerImage" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" width="320" height="120" alt="some text">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
```

Comment: `div` elements do not have load events.  `window` does.  images do.  iframes do. other media elements do most likely.  `div`s do not.  If you put a console.log inside the method you are trying to run on load, you will see it is not executing.

Comment: thanks @Taplar, I managed to get this workoing, but I have the html code inside php foreach and the banners are changing just in the first foreach data and not changing in the second !

Comment: `php` runs on the server, not the client.  so i'm not sure how any looping on the server side would affect the looping you are trying to implement on the client.

Comment: Unless you are saying that the php loop generates duplicate html elements, that only one works with.  If that is the case, can you please update your question to show the duplicated markup, and also provide any changes you have made to the original code presented.

Comment: @Taplar I updated the code I used and it's working but only in the first row of foreach data

Comment: You're example oes not have multiple rows, as far as I can see.  Please show an example with multiple rows.

Comment: it's a foreach data from the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page  You're issue is you are repeating ids.  Ids are expected to be unique per page.  You should use a class instead, and adjust your logic to use contextual lookups.

Answer (score 1):

This code here will change the image and the link every 5 seconds.

```js
var links = ["http://site","http://site"];
var images = ["https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500","https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"];

var i = 0;
var renew = setInterval(function(){    
    document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i];
    document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i];
    i++;
    
    if (i == links.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">

        <a id="bannerLink" href="http://site" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
            <img id="bannerImage" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" width="320" height="120" alt="some text">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I rearranged the loop so it will always change an image every 5 seconds. Before you have the reset taking an entire round, adding 5 seconds.

I also changed `500` to `5000` (it's in milliseconds)

Comment: thanks, but it's the same it changes only on the first row of foreach data !

Comment: What do you mean by "the first row of foreach data"? It should use all the data that it is given. Could you give an example or a way to replicate the issue?